# String join function in C# using a list, apply join to first item

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list with ID's.

Example:

123

456

789

What I want to do is to return all the elements in a single string, and seperate them with ' #'.

My result would be: 
 #123 #456 #789

I tried this by doing the following:

```
//Start with a # at first

seperatedString = "#";

seperatedString = String.Join(" #", list.ToArray());
```

But my result is: 123 #456 #789

Why isn't my seperator applied to the first element of the string?

Comment: Because that is not what string.Join() does, and the documentation says so: "Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a collection, using the specified separator *between each element or member*."

Comment: That's how `String.Join` should work. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Because it is designed to behave that way... Can you explain why you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seperatedString = seperatedString + String.Join(" #", list.ToArray());`

Comment: This is nice because it also prevents a space from being prepended before the # for the first item in the list, which I doubt the OP would want, since you used the originally seeded separatedString, which had only "#" in it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't applied to the first element, because it is a "separater". You can add it onto the beginning manually or you can use linq, like so:

```
string result = string.Join(string.Empty, (new[] { 123, 456, 789 }).Select(i => "#" + i));
```